# Create clean URL from text in Excel

Tags: regex, excel

I want to create a clean URL from a text such as this one:

> Alpha Tests' Purchase of Berta Global Associates (C)

The URL should look like this:

> alpha-tests-purchase-of-berta-global-associates-c

Currently I use this formula in Excel:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A38;"--";"-");" / ";"-");"  ";"-");": ";"-");" - ";"-");"_";"-");"?";"");",";"");".";"");"'";"");")";"");"(";"");":";"");" ";"-");"&";"and");"!";"");"/";"-");"""";""))
```

However, I don't seem to catch all special symbols etc. and as a consequence my URLs are not as clean as I want them to be.

Do you know an Excel formula or VBA code, which ensures that all special symbols are properly converted to a clean URL?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you use English letters only or do you want to keep all Unicode letters?

Comment: English letters only. As I want to use those URL als Wordpress links (e.g. exampledomain.com/alpha-tests-purchase-of-berta-global-associates-c)

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest the following Function that you can put into a VBA module and use a normal formula:

```
Function NormalizeToUrl(cell As Range)

Dim strPattern As String
Dim regEx As Object

Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
strPattern = "[^\w-]+"

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

NormalizeToUrl = LCase(regEx.Replace(Replace(cell.Value, " ", "-"), ""))
End Function
```

[image]

The point is that we replace all spaces with hyphens at the beginning, then use a regex that matches any non-word and non-hyphen characters and remove them with `RegExp.Replace`.

**UPDATE**:

After your comments, it is still unclear what you want to do with Unicode letters. Delete or replace with hyphen. Here is a function that I tried to rebuild from your formula, but the logics may be flawed. I would prefer a generic approach above.

```
Function NormalizeToUrl(cell As Range)

Dim strPattern As String
Dim regEx As Object

Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
strPattern = "[^\w -]"

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[?,.')(:!""]+" ' THESE ARE REMOVED
End With

NormalizeToUrl = regEx.Replace(cell.Value, "")
NormalizeToUrl = Replace(NormalizeToUrl, "&", "and") ' & TURNS INTO "and"

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = strPattern ' WE REPLACE ALL NON-WORD CHARS WITH HYPHEN
End With
NormalizeToUrl = LCase(regEx.Replace(Replace(NormalizeToUrl, " ", "-"), "-"))
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "--+" ' WE SHRINK ALL HYPHEN SEQUENCES TO SINGLE HYPHEN
End With
NormalizeToUrl = regEx.Replace(NormalizeToUrl, "-")
End Function
```

Comment: This seems to work. However, special characters seem to not get properly replaced. For example, I just stumbled upon an @ symbol or ç. They just get deleted, but not replaced. How can this values be properly replaced as well?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I guess I didn't understand your question correctly. Could you adjust the above VGA code as mentioned (with the range) to help define nonsupported letters? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, as I don't assume that Wordpress can properly use this special symbols in a URL. So there should neither be ç, é, @ nor any similar special symbols be in there. I hope this helps!